# Writing To The Response in Rails? (Like "echo" in PHP)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, translation

I know that I can do this in Rails:

```
<%="hello" %>
```

but is there any way to do this

```
<%
echo "hello"
%>
```

and get it to show up in the response?

Comment: Yeah. The object exists but the method doesn't :)  undefined method `write' for #<ActionController::CgiResponse:0xb65c9930>

Comment: CgiResponse?  Use ActionController::CgiResponse.out

Comment: what's wrong with <%="hello" %> ?

Comment: This is a confusing question - what is <%= "hello" %> not doing for you?

Comment: Hi Can, nothing is wrong with it, but it makes no sense to close and open tags between code. In the example above it's trivial, of course.

Comment: you shouldn't have to include that much code in your views anyway. most of that code might belong to your controller.

Comment: Thanks Can, you're right, but I like to know all of my options.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried `concat`.

I have seen this when wandering in Rails documentation. Not sure at all since I am very new to Rails.

Answer (score 13):

What you have to write is

```
<% concat "bank" %>
```

now you can do something like

```
<%
  10.times do
    concat "cat"
  end
%>
```

for ten cat

Comment: Precisely. In this context it makes sense to use concat instead of <%=. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I had no idea what that binding was, myself.

Answer (score 6):

Use `concat`, I've tried it and it works.
However if you need to use HTML chars use:

```
concat(sanitize("STRING"))
```

or open your `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` and write:

```
def echo(str)
    concat sanitize str
end
```

so you can just type: `echo "hello<br />\n"`

Comment: what happens if you don't sanitize

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for "print" or "puts", depending on whether or not you want a newline (probably not).  Almost every object implements .to_s, which works also, though my feeling is that there's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do.  Any more context on this?

Comment: Thanks, no, I want to see it on the client, not on the console.

Comment: There's no reason why it wouldn't work on the console.  <%=puts "Any Ruby code goes here" %>

Comment: -1, puts (or p) outputs to STDOUT by default, which is NOT where the response is generated. And <%= puts ... %> will produce an empty string in the response, puts (or p) return nil and nil.to_s == "".

Comment: thanks Samuel. I've never had more incorrect answers for a question. Somewhere between what I *should* do and what I *can* do, many answerers got lost.