# How to get content type of a given url inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2, content-type

I want to know the content type of a given url input by the user inside my Javascript code. Actually, I have a drop-down list (html,csv,xls etc.) and I want to make it so when the user inputs an url, I want to detect the type of the content of the url and based on this type I want to set the value of my drop-down list (html,csv,xls etc.). I know, I can get the content type using Ruby like this :

```
require 'open-uri'
str = open('http://example.com')
str.content_type #=> "text/html"
```

or, also, I could use curl to get the content and then parse it to know the content type. But, I need to do this inside my Javascript code because of my need explained above. Any thought ?

**EDIT_1 :**

I tried this code in my javascript :

```
    $("#wiki_form_url").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "content.rb",
            data: {
//                input_url: $("#wiki_form_url").val()
            },
            dataType: "html"
        }).done(function (data) {
                    // `data` contains the content-type
                    alert('Success !!!');
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("failed AJAX call");
                });
    });
```

I have a ruby script content.rb inside which I do :

```
require 'open-uri'

str = open('http://www.ofdp.org/benchmark_indices/25')
str.content_type
```

But, it does not seem to work. I am getting Ajax failure. May be it's because of url path of the script content.rb ? How should I specify a script path here ? (Relative or absolute)

Comment: What environment is that JavaScript running in? Node? WSH? A browser extension? A web page in a browser?

Comment: Have you selected a library or api for making HTTP requests already? If so, which?

Comment: I think you'll have to make an AJAX request to your server, then use your code above, respond to the AJAX, and do things appropriately. You won't be able to make cross-domain requests with Javascript and get their content type

Comment: No, I did not select anything specifically. I am working on Rails 3.2 project and using little bit of JavaScript. I am not that expert in Javascript.

Comment: What environment is that JavaScript running in? Node? WSH? A browser extension? A web page in a browser? (The use of Rails implies the latter, but it isn't certain).

Comment: I have used Rails built in Ajax using remote => true option before. Could you please give some example code how to use Ajax for this purpose using my above ruby code ? @Ian

Comment: @Quentin yes, it is a web page in a browser.

Comment: I guess my point is that you can't do it directly from Javascript. So from your Javascript, you'd have to make an AJAX call to a Ruby method on the server. I've never worked with RoR, so I don't know how to map a URL to a method. Anyways, you'd make an AJAX request to that URL, run your Ruby code above, and return `str.content_type` as the AJAX response. Then, in your Javascript, you'd get the AJAX response and manipulate the dropdown based on the result. You aren't using jQuery, are you? It would make AJAX calls a little easier, otherwise a code example will be a little longer

Comment: Yes, I am using jQuery. Could you please give an example ? !@Ian

Comment: @KeenLearner I posted an answer. I'm not sure how helpful it would be, since I've never used RoR and I don't know your code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I could figure out the whole thing with the great help of @Ian. Here is my completed code : In javascript file :

```
    $("#wiki_form_url").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/wiki_forms/content",
            data: {
                input_url: $("#wiki_form_url").val()
            },
            dataType: "text"
        }).done(function (data) {
                    // `data` contains the content-type
                    alert('Success');
                    console.log(data);
//                    alert(data);
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("failed AJAX call");
                });
    });
```

Inside my wiki_forms controller I created a new method named content :

```
  def content 
    req = open(params[:input_url])
    render :text => req.content_type 
  end
```

Then added a new route in routes.rb file :

```
  get "/wiki_forms/content" => 'wiki_forms#content'
```

and used **/wiki_forms/content** as the ajax request url. And, everything is working nicely now.

Answer (score 1):

The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you from using client side JavaScript to directly discover information about arbitrary URIs (URIs you control are a different story).

You'll need to get that information with another technology, such as your server side Ruby.

You could do this by simply submitting a form to the server and returning a new webpage to the browser.

If you don't want to leave the page, then you can pass the data using Ajax. There are no shortage of Ajax tutorials out there, [here is a good one from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of an AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button_check").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Your URL",
            data: {
                input_url: $("#textbox_id").val()
            },
            dataType: "html"
        }).done(function (data) {
            // `data` contains the content-type
            alert(data);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("failed AJAX call");
        });
    });
});
```

Where your HTML is something like:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox_id" />
<input type="button" id="button_check" value="Submit" />
```

And your Ruby code would be something like:

```
require 'open-uri'
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    req = open(params[:input_url])
    render :text => req.content_type
  end
end
```

I have never used RoR before, so I have no idea if this is right or works in the slightest. But it's what I could quickly conjure up when scrambling through several tutorials. It's simply the *concept* you seem to be looking for. You'll need to figure out how to map a URL to this method, and then update the AJAX option `url` to use that.

So in the Javascript code - in the `done` method, that means the whole AJAX request was successful and the `data` variable should contain the result from the Ruby code `req.content_type`.

Comment: @KeenLearner Sounds good! I really don't know how to map a URL to a controller/action, so you'll definitely need to change that. There's just many things I'm not sure about with RoR :) Obviously you'll have to update the URL stuff. Let me know what you find out with this type of code. Feel free to post what you try to use in your original question and any errors/messages you get!

Comment: @KeenLearner A few things. Again, I'm not sure how RoR works, but with most programming languages, you have to print a value to the response. With my example, I used `render` (what I found from searching online). So you can't just have `str.content_type` in your code...you need to render it somehow. Since you aren't using Controllers or whatever I found, you might need to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504839/writing-to-the-response-in-rails-like-echo-in-php . Also, you might want to use `dataType: "text"` in your Javascript - not "html".

Comment: @KeenLearner Also, can you look at your browser's console? Like Firebug or Developer Tools? That way, you could look at the AJAX request and see what the problem might be - like a 500 error (server error) or 404 (URL path not found), and maybe even display RoR's explanation. Also, are you able to debug with Ruby and see if the request ever hits the server?

Comment: @KeenLearner It might be best to reference the Ruby file by absolute path, just to make sure that couldn't be a problem. Are you sure the Ruby file is in a directory that will evaluate a Ruby file and not just return its contents? Are you serving these files with a (local) server or just accessing them all with your filesystem?

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/wiki_forms/content.rb 404 (Not Found) 

this is the error in console

Comment: @KeenLearner Dumb question but, is "content.rb" in that specific directory? And have you restarted your server to make sure it has picked it up? Some servers require being restarted, some don't. What if you specify an absolute path? Do you know the actual path to the file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27113/discussion-between-keen-learner-and-ian)