# Check url content type with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, content-type

In order to conserve server resources I'm looking for a way to retrieve the content type of a given url using javascript. It should not download the complete content from the url only the headers. Is this possible with the restrictions javascript has.

Comment: I suppose you had a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685866/how-to-get-content-type-of-a-given-url-inside-javascript)?

Comment: make a HEAD request. TADA!

Comment: So I gather is impossible for an external url

Comment: It is not impossible, it depends on the server has CORS enabled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make an Ajax call with a head request.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open('HEAD', url);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.status);
        console.log(this.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
    }
};
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: how about cross origin urls ?

Comment: @Exlord if they have CORs sure, if they don't, get your serverside to do it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI if your server doesn't allow HEAD requests but does allow GET requests, you can do this by limiting the range of the GET request.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=0");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
  }
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: This worked for me. Also, if you want to use an arrow function instead of the nameless function, change "this" for "xmlhttp".