# How to check if a iframe has text or pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, iframe

I have a iframe, which could either have a text message or a pdf and this text or pdf is very random in nature.

```
$('<iframe>', {
                src: myRenderUrl,
                id:  'myIframe',
                frameborder: 0,
                scrolling: 'no',
                width : '100%',
                height : '100%',
            }).prependTo('#myDiv');
```

but after rendering the same I want to check if the iframe contains a pdf or a text, Is there a way to do this using the jquery/js

I found a way using the offsetHeight

```
  if($("#myIframe").offsetHeight != undefined){
    // do something
    }
```

But the same thing is not helpful ,

Then using the below mentioned code I get the text but for pdf I gets the error

```
try {
       var iframe = $("#myIframe");
       content = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
       // text message obtained
    }
    catch(error) {
       console.error(error);
       // seems like obtained a pdf ,but not sure
    }
```

But is there any other better way where it can be categorized if the iframe has text message or a pdf.

Comment: What does `myRenderUrl` look like?

Comment: Its a url to send the ajax request , some thing like https://localhost/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=120001&p_auth=yXXw1pTK&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_id=MYPROJECT&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_resource_id=downloadPDF&_MYPROJECT_data=SOMEKEY

Comment: Would checking the `p_p_resource_id` URL parameter be acceptable? i.e. `p_p_resource_id=downloadPDF`

Comment: yes , it can be accessed.

Comment: In that case, can't you just use `(new URL(myRenderUrl)).searchParams.get("p_p_resource_id")` and check whether or not the return value is `downloadPDF`?

Comment: but this url is used to send the request , and not while getting the response

Comment: I see, so a `downloadPDF` URL might not show a PDF?

Comment: It may or may not show the pdf depending on the business logic. It could either bring a pdf on response or it could bring some text/html as per the business logic.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24050265/7290573

Comment: but its not the normal ajax , its the iframe that is sending the ajax request